# Range implications of C extension on double bass

Tags: fingering, double-bass, instrument-range

I know the C-extension allows playing C1 on a double bass, but it's not entirely clear to me what the implications are of using it:

AFAICT if none of the mechanical fingers are used you can play C1 by bowing the open string, but it's impossible to play a C#, D, D#? (Based on [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_bass#/media/File:Double_bass_C_extension.jpg))
Since you can't reach for those notes due to the mechanical fingers being in the way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this video, particularly from 1'35"

You finger from the left (player's view).   The 'clips' are on the right.  They don't obstruct fingering.

Comment: Haha, ah yes of course. Silly me :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, you set the bottom note required in the piece you are playing by clipping that note off.  Sometimes you might have time to clip off a note during a passage and then unclipping it again, depending on what the music requires.  You have to initially read through the music to find out what clips you need to where and write instructions in the relevant places (a bit like a harp player with their pedalling instructions).